# DateTimeOffset.Now in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm executing a INSERT to a sql 2008 db. How do I specify in T-SQL to insert NOW in a DATETIMEOFFSET column? GETDATE()?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Maybe.

This would give you the local time of the server where SQL is installed.

Do you want to store timezone etc too? If so, [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx)() may be better

Comment: Actually you get an offset (e.g. +02:00), not a time zone (e.g. 'W. Europe Standard Time').

Comment: Then you need something like `DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone`. The problem is ambiguity: multiple timezones can have the same time offset from UTC